# how to write a function to check the presence of an element html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to write a function for checking the presence of an element with a certain id.
I have these IDs for verification set in an array:
let CartArray = ["cart-0", "cart-1", "cart-2", "cart-3"];

JavaScript:

```
      //=== === === Cart === === ===\\
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //========= checking the presence of items in the cart when the page is loaded =========\\
        if(document.getElementById('myDIV').childElementCount == 0) {
          document.getElementById('myDIV').innerHTML = "cart is empty";
        }
        
        const element = document.getElementById('myDIV');
        const numberOfChildren = element.childElementCount; //====== Number of items in the cart

        //========= Changing ::before for the cart when the page is loaded =========\\
        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++) {
          CartCount++;
        }
        document.getElementById("CountCartS").setAttribute('CartCountS', CartCount);

        //========= Add to cart (number changes) =========\\
        $("#button-count").click(function () {
          CartCount++;
          document.getElementById("CountCartS").setAttribute('CartCountS', CartCount);
        });

        const button = document.querySelector('#button');
        
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
          for(var i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++) {
            const parent = document.getElementById('myDIV');
            const child = parent.children[i];
            
            if(parent.childElementCount > 0) {
              if(child.id == CartArray[i]) {
                alert(child.id + " --- there is a div with this id");
              }
              else if(child.id != CartArray[i]) {
                alert(child.id + " --- does not have a div with that id");
              }
            }
            else if(parent.childElementCount == 0) {
              document.getElementById('myDIV').innerHTML = "cart is empty";
            }
            else {
              alert("Error");
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

the code doesn't fit in stackoverflow, so I'm adding a link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/SHvari_David_Simba/pen/JjBNXzp

I tried to check the presence of the item by the id from the array, but nothing happened

Comment: Your code already gets element references. To see if there is an actual element returned, just check the return value. For example `const foo = document.getElementById("bar"); if(foo) { // element exists } else { // element doesn't exist }`

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:jquery], for which there's a well established method.  See duplicate.   Having voted, I see it doesn't look like you're using jquery other than for doc.ready.  The existing answer does include vanilla js solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `myelement.querySelector('[id="' + id + '"]')` to search children by id:

```js
let CartArray = ["cart-0", "cart-1", "cart-2", "cart-3"];

function isChildExists(parent)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < CartArray.length; i++)
  {
    if (parent.querySelector('[id="' + CartArray[i] + '"]'))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function check(el)
{
  el.dataset.exists = isChildExists(el.parentNode);
}
```

```css
[id]::before
{
  content: attr(id) " " attr(data-exists);
}
```

```html
<div><button id="cart-0" onclick="check(this)"></button></div>
<div><button id="cart-1" onclick="check(this)"></button></div>
<div><button id="cart-2" onclick="check(this)"></button></div>
<div><button id="cart-3" onclick="check(this)"></button></div>
<div><button id="cart-4" onclick="check(this)"></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your need.

```js
function hasDocumentElementById(id){
  return !!document.getElementById(id); // returns boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * Get existing id 
 *
 * @param {Array} ids List of id 
 * @returns An array of existing id
 */
function getExistingIds(ids) {
  return ids.filter(id => document.getElementById(id) ? true : false)
}


/**
 * Check id existence
 * 
 * @param {Array} ids List of id 
 * @returns An array of boolean, true if id is exist, and false if it's not 
 */
function checkIds(ids) {
  return ids.map(id => document.getElementById(id) ? true : false)
}
```